# Pivot table column for % of Type Count

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Let's say I have a pivot table with

Column A = Type
Column B = Total Count of All Types (Type A, Type B, etc.)
Column C = Total Count of All Types, Shown as % of Grand Total

I would a Column D that shows 'Total Count of EACH Type, Shown as % of Grand Total'. How would I accomplish that?

An example is attached below. Thank you for any help you can provide!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBTtj.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post & add some sample data you have used to create Pivot Table will help us to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample.

[image]

Then I create a pivot table, drag the field of **Count** into **Values** 3 times, each of them run the calculation of SUM by default.

[image]

For Column C, click **Sum of Count2** > Value Field of Settings > select **% of Grand of Total** for "Show Values As" > click "Number format" > Percentage with 1 of Decimal places > OK.

For Column D, click **Sum of Count3** > Value Field of Settings > select **% of Parent of Total** for "Show Values As" based field of **Type** > click "Number format" > Percentage with none of Decimal places > OK.

[image]

At last we could get the following result as following picture.

[image]